# Python - packing different count of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a working dictionary, it works, but I have problem.
I have to pack a lot of data, but the problem is that I have variable count of strings.
I want to pack in every step, I was using

```
struct.pack(polozka.param, polozka.text, 0, polozka.pointer, polozka.size)
```

where `polozka.param` are parameters,
 `.text` is english word,
 `0` is offset, `.pointer` is pointing to the translation of the word in language, and `.size` is size required.

I didn't come up with any other idea so far, and I would be grateful for every advice i can find :)

If I start my dictionary I have result for example

```
Active
 -translated word
Active
 -translated word
```

but want to have

```
Active
 -translated word, translated word,etc.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't access the keys of a dictionary using attributes (`.`), if you have a dictionary you use `dictionary['key']`.

And not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I assume what you are looking for is a data structure like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'Active': ['translated word', 'translated word'],
    'foo': []
}
```

Here are the keys of the dictionary a string and the values are corresponding lists, which have your translated words in it (also strings).

Also, I'd be good if you could provide some code.

Comment: sory, i ll comment not here, missclick